# Add CSS class when user hits tab key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 14 application I am trying to add "display: block" when user reaches an element using the tab key and want to remove the "display:block" when user tabs out of the element.

I was able to achieve the first part (add "display: block" when user reaches and element using the tab key) but not sure how to remove the "display:block" once user tabs out.
Here is my code.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.tab', ['$event'])onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
if (event.key === "Tab" && (event.target as Element).classList.contains('some-class')) {
  this.renderer.addClass(this.test?.nativeElement, 'd-block');
}}
```

Need some help please.Is there any better way to achieve this instead of using hostlistener?

Comment: Why specifically when the user uses the tab key to get to the element? Do you not just mean 'when the element has focus'?

Comment: Hey Rory, well actually I am actually doing this for Accessibility so when user is navigating through the page using tab keys, I want to add display block

Comment: Just use the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) selector?

Comment: Hi DarkBee how do I capture the tab to use the :focus selector. I hope you mean use :focus in css

Comment: The pseudo-class `:focus` is automatically assigned to any element which has the focus, whether this was done by clicking the element or traversing the document with `TAB`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focus` event to toggle a variable and `blur` to toggle it back, you can even watch for `mouseover` and `mouseout` and use [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to toggle the styles! You can also do for [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) also the same!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  styles: [
    `
    h1,.test {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    .d-block {
      display: block;
    }
    `,
  ],
  template: `
  <div tabindex="1">test</div>
  <div tabindex="1">test</div>
  
  <span class="test" tabindex="1" [ngClass]="{'d-block': isFocus2}" (mouseover)="isFocus2 = true;" (focus)="isFocus2 = true;" (mouseout)="isFocus2 = false;" (blur)="isFocus2 = false;">Hello from {{ name }}!</span>
  <div tabindex="1">test</div>
  <div tabindex="1">test</div>
    <h1 tabindex="1" [ngStyle]="{'display': isFocus ? 'block' : 'inline'}" (mouseover)="isFocus = true;" (focus)="isFocus = true;" (mouseout)="isFocus = false;" (blur)="isFocus = false;">Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  isFocus = false;
  isFocus2 = false;
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xefgyk)